# Cannot find the path of my model in flask

Tags: python, flask

My directory structure looks like this:

```
- project
  - server.py
  - test-model (dir)
```

My script looks like this:

```
@app.route("/spacy/entities", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def spacy_entities():
    import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load('test-model')   // also tried './test-model'
```

> Can't find model 'test-model'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

I am running this script in vagrant.

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/sideprojects/project$ pwd
/home/vagrant/Code/sideprojects/project
```

The things I have tried:

```
1. os.path.realpath('.') -> /home/vagrant/Code
2. os.path.realpath(__file__) -> /home/vagrant/Code/server.py
3. os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) -> /home/vagrant/Code
```

But it should be `/home/vagrant/Code/sideprojects/project` so that it can find 'test-model'. What am I doing wrong?

(I am trying to avoid putting a hard-coded path)

Edit: I tried:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/sideprojects/project'
nlp = spacy.load(path + "/test-model")
```

> Can't find model '/home/vagrant/Code/sideprojects/project/test-model'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

The full error is:

> File "server.py", line 40, in spacy_entities
>           nlp = spacy.load(path + "/goal1")
>         File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/**init**.py", line 30, in load
>           return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
>         File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 169, in load_model
>           raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
>
> OSError: [E050] Can't find model '/home/vagrant/Code/sideprojects/project/test-model'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Comment: if you are running server.py as to run flask server then it should work, otherwise give path from the project base root, like, `spacy.load('project/test-model')`

Comment: But then I'd miss the `/sideprojects` part and if I end up putting `'sideprojects/project/test-model'`, no? Is there any way to just say `getpath(./test-model')` kind of thing? Currently I am running it as `python3 server.py` but eventually I'll want to use with nohup and I don't want it to get messed/hard-coded for the future (or even if I deploy it to a server)

Comment: well in that case,  write a function with load the spacy model and return loaded nlp object and call that object on this route, i simple term , write a function which load the ner model perfectly with your project schema and then in routes call that object like `nlp = load_model()`

Comment: @temmo I added an edit but still couldn't make it work even with (partially) hard-coded path. btw, I'm python noob - can you guide me on what you mean by _write a function with load the spacy model and return loaded nlp object and call that object on this route_?

Comment: [see this](https://ideone.com/WIiDBg)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made it work. If you add an answer I can accept it

Comment: done added a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a new py file say `modelload.py` then inside this create a a fucntion say `load_model` in this function load the spacy model

a sample code

```
# modelload.py
# just make a script which load model and make a function to it 

import spacy
model_path = 'test-model' # modifed this to your path and check if this is working fine and load correctly

def load_model(path=None):
    if path is None:
          path = model_path

    nlp = spacy.load(path)
    return nlp


# end
```

in your routing script/ `server.py` file import this model as a object like this

```
# server.py

@app.route("/spacy/entities", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def spacy_entities():
    from modelload import load_model
    nlp = load_model() 
    """give other model names if you want to laod new model 
      by default it is `test-model`"""
```

Comment: Thanks again: P.S: I used `model_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/test-model'`